# Can you sleep in Canberra airport or does it close overnight?

Tags: air-travel, airports, australia, opening-hours, canberra

I've slept overnight in Melbourne Airport, in Australia. I know you can't do this in Sydney Airport (they close). However I can't find this info for Canberra.

I've found a cheap flight that goes via Canberra overnight, and I'm quite happy sleeping on the floor if it's possible.  But sleepinginairports.net doesn't have any reviews or info, and I can't find opening hours on the airport website or elsewhere.  It's only recently started having international flights again, so information seems to be scarce.

Question: Can you stay in the airport overnight?

Comment: Sleeping in airports says: "The airport is open 4:30AM until 30 minutes after last flight." I don't know how accurate it is.

Comment: While you can't sleep in the airport, there is decent hotel (Vibe Hotel) nearby which you can stay overnight. If you don't mind sleeping in the open, it's another option as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no information about opening hours on their website but:

1. https://www.canberraairport.com.au/travellers/flight-information/departures/ shows no flights between midnight and 06:00.
2. https://www.canberraairport.com.au/travellers/retail-services/dining/ restaurants seem to close at 9pm. That wouldn't make sense if the airport was open 24/7.

Seeing this, I'd wager the airport closes after last flight, and opens around 04:30~05:00.

Comment: Because flight operations have nothing to do with airport opening hours. Munich airport also shows [no flights between 23:15 an 6:00](https://www.munich-airport.com/all-departures-1450598#departures) tonigh (in fact, only very few flights [are allowed during this time](https://www.munich-airport.com/night-flight-264466), and they are the kind that won't appear on the list). Restaurants close, too, as far as I can tell. When my flight from Portugal arrived late in August (touchdown was 23:55), the airport was half dark and pretty much empty. However...

Comment: ... the airport doesn't close at night. At least one information counter [is open 24/7](https://www.munich-airport.com/information-service-965597) which, for me, implies that the airport is open. Plus, one girl who was on said flight with me slept in the airport both before going to Portugal and after arriving back home. AFAIK, the same holds true for other German airports (e.g. Stuttgart), though I can't find a reference right now.

Comment: Yep. I've overnighted in a number of airports where everything closes except the rest rooms, after the last flight comes in. It's not indicative.